# Loop through all the attributes of a node using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml that stores table definations. How can I loop through each column of the passed tablename (only one occurrence of each table) and their attributes using XDocument (C# 3.5)

Ex: If user passes CurrencySummary, I want to read each column and all it's attributes like HeaderDescription, HeaderName etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TableDef>
  <CurrencySummary>
    <Column Name="Currency" HeaderDescription="Currency" HeaderName="Currency" ColumnType="TableColumnType.Text" IsHidden = "false" Position="0" Width="100" />
    <Column Name="ParamortizedValue" HeaderDescription="Par/amortized value" HeaderName="paramortizedvalue" ColumnType="TableColumnType.Number" IsHidden = "false" Position="1" Width="200" />
    <Column Name="PercentBondTotal" HeaderDescription="% of bond total" HeaderName="percentbondtotal" ColumnType="TableColumnType.Number" IsHidden = "false" Position="2" Width="150" />
  </CurrencySummary>
  <CallSchedule>
    <Column Name="Calldate" HeaderDescription="Call date" HeaderName="Calldate" ColumnType="TableColumnType.Text" IsHidden = "false" Position="0" Width="100" />
    <Column Name="Issue" HeaderDescription="Issue" HeaderName="Issue" ColumnType="TableColumnType.Text" IsHidden = "false" Position="1" Width="100" />
    <Column Name="ParamortizedValue" HeaderDescription="Par/amortized value" HeaderName="paramortizedvalue" ColumnType="TableColumnType.Number" IsHidden = "false" Position="2" Width="200" />
    <Column Name="PercentBondTotal" HeaderDescription="% of bond total" HeaderName="percentbondtotal" ColumnType="TableColumnType.Number" IsHidden = "false" Position="3" Width="150" />
  </CallSchedule>
</TableDef>
```

I am trying to achieve this by: (edited: as per Henk's suggestion)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("TableDefinations.xml");
var cols = doc.Descendants("CurrencySummary").First();
foreach (var col in cols.Elements())
{
    foreach (XAttribute at in col.Attributes())
    {
        //do something with the at.Name and at.Value
    }
}
```

Is this is efficient way or if there is anything better than this?

Comment: I have added the code above, is it the right way or is there a better way?

Comment: Looks OK, so what is the remaining question?

Comment: Henk, Sorry for not been specific. I want to know if this is the best way in my scenario?

Comment: Jodrell, I know.. Going forward, I will make sure to stick to my question and do not edit the question that often :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a little on how many `<CurrencySummary>`s there are and if their place matters.

```
var summ = doc.Descendants("CurrencySummary").First();

foreach (var col in summ.Elements())
   ...
```

Comment: table will be unique. so only one "CurrencySummary" in xml and at any position.

Comment: Then my `.First()` is more appropriate than your `foreach()`. But both will work.

Comment: one less foreach loop.. much neater.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** OP not on .Net 4, so not using `SelectMany`, if `Single()` not .Net 4.0 substitute with `First()`

Looks like you there should be only one `"CurrencySummary"` so ...

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("TableDefinations.xml");
foreach(XElement col in doc.Descendants("CurrencySummary").Single().Elements())
{
    foreach(XAttribute at in col.Attributes())
    {
        at...
    }
}
```

Will iterate through all the attributes of all the elements in the one and only CurrencySummary element, anywhere in the TableDefninations.xml.

Comment: OK because `a.Parent()` lets you access the rest.

Comment: Somehow I was not able to compile this piece of code. Says XElement doesn't contain definition for SelectMany(). Is it part of 4.0?

Comment: Yep, part of .Net 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jodrell for the code and information. We are not yet on 4.0 but will keep this in mind. Sorry for not been clear with the version in my question.