# Iterate through all unknown XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I want to iterate through all attributes from all given tags in an XML file with C# like in this example.

```
<TAG1 Attribute1="1234" Attribute2="1234" Attribute3="1234">
      <TAG2 xpq="123" abc="000" lkj="123"/>
</TAG1>
```

The XML is very long and the tags and attribute naming can change. 
So I must find a way to iterate through them with unknown naming.
I have tested it with

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\PathToXml\File.xml");
var optionTitle = reader.Name;                           
var AttributeName = reader.LocalName;
var AttributeValue = reader.GetAttribute(AttributeName);
var itemValue = new ListViewItem(new[] { optionTitle, AttributeName, AttributeValue });
listView1.Items.Add(itemValue);
```

But I only get the tag names and nothing else...

Does anyone have an idea for me?

Comment: Duplicate shows XmlReader solution or if you are fine with LINQ-to-XML - duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253565/loop-through-all-the-attributes-of-a-node-using-xdocument.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [Linq2Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693072.aspx)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
foreach(var attr in xDoc.Descendants("TAG1").First().Attributes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(attr.Name + " " + attr.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/IT-IT/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which provides a much simpler access to XML documents.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\PathToXml\File.xml");
foreach(var el in doc.Descendants())
   foreach(var attr in el.Attributes())
   {
        var itemValue = new ListViewItem(new[] { el.TagName, attr.Name, attr.Value });
        listView1.Items.Add(itemValue);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `XDocument` to load your xml file. Then get all the attributes by using `XElement.Attributes` like this

```
var document = XDocument.Load("C:\\PathToXml\File.xml");
foreach (var attribute in document.Root.Attributes)
{
    //process the attribute
    //attribute.Name
    //attribute.Value
}
```